# Method Reference for String uppercase java 8

Tags: java-8

In java 8, method reference in String uppercase() is not static. Then how method reference is working? String :: toUpperCase().

Answer (score 1):

You might want to show the type of the Interface this is assigned to, but for example

```
Function<String, String> f = String::toUpperCase;
```

Is equivalent to

```
Function<String, String> f = s -> s.toUpperCase();
```

See
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html